# $\mathbb{C}$ is not the splitting field of any polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ (without cardinality)

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I came across this exercise in Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra. Using a cardinality argument, the splitting field of polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ would form a finite-dimensional rational vector space, while $\mathbb{C}$ is an infinite-dimensional rational vector space. Is there a different way to go about this problem?

Answer (score 5):

The existence of a transcendental number provides such a proof.

Comment: +1. If one doesn't want to get his/her hands dirty with transcendental numbers, one can appeal to different methods; e.g., $\mathbb{C}$ contains $\sqrt[n]{2}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and hence an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[n]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $X^{n}-2$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein at $2$).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is also interesting to you: Let $p_i$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$ be pairwise different prime numbers. Then the set $\{log(p_i): i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is linearly independent over the rationals. So not even the real numbers can be a finite dimensional vector space over the rationals. In particular the complex number can't be the splitting field of a single polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Another (slightly different) way to attack this problem: suppose $\;\Bbb C\;$ is the splitting field of $\;p(x)\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$, and let $\;w_1,...,w_n\;$ be the roots of $\;p(x)\;$ .

Then $\;p(x)\;$ already splits in $\;\Bbb Q(w_1,...,w_n)\subsetneq\Bbb C\;$ . The sharp contention follows either by dimension arguments or else because, for example,

$$\pi\in\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb Q(w_1,...,w_n)\;$$

Comment: Trascendence of $\pi$ is quite hard to prove.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thank you. For whom? I think that anyone with one good year of real analysis can manage at least some of the proofs: http://sixthform.info/maths/files/pitrans.pdf  And with a little more a more succint proof can be given: http://people.math.sc.edu/filaseta/gradcourses/Math785/Math785Notes6.pdf